# 404 for some custom taxonomy not ALL taxonomy

Tags: posts, customization, taxonomy

i created taxonomy and post type & Metabox using Easy Content Types

some custom taxonomy work correctly, but i don't know why one of my custom taxonomy , each time i try to access it , i got 404 page not found

but i can access single post page.

my problem only with taxonomy term.

my post type name is services
and my taxonomy name is services 
also i have another taxonomy called location

location working correctly, but services no.

i tried to remove .htacess to rebuild it
and i tried to update my permalink but nothing has been changed

Comment: if you have a post type and taxonomy that share the same name, you've likely created conflicting query vars and/or URLs. what is the URL structure for taxonomy and post type?

Comment: @Milo yes same name for custom post type and custom taxonomy , ( services ) : http://www.sitename.com/services/garage-banshar/